# Hide fields from ModelView in Flask-admin form_create

Tags: flask-admin

Is there a proper way of excluding fields from showing up in the create form of Flask-admin? I would normally do something like this in order to specify which fields to show on the create and edit form:

```
class UserView(sqla.ModelView):
    form_create_rules = { 'username' }
    form_edit_rules = ('username', 'photos')
```

Even though this works as expected, I get the following warning when running my application:

```
UserWarning: Fields missing from ruleset: photos
  warnings.warn(text)
```

Is there a better way of defining what fields to show on each form that doesn't give me that error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use properties of the ModelView class:

> `form_columns` - Collection of the model field names for the form.
>   If set to None will get them from the model.

or

> `form_excluded_columns` - Collection of the model field names for
>   the form. If set to None will get them from the model.

You can find more info inside [Flask-Admin Docs](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/?highlight=form_columns).

I also should mention that this will work for both **Create** and **Edit** forms.

Comment: Strange I didn't notice those two, thanks a lot! Makes sense now. :)

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, this property needs to be on the model or the ModelView?

Comment: These are both properties on the ModelView subclass.

Comment: his question hide input which means add hidden property to the input , form_excluded_columns will remove the field from the form not hide it, so if you try to change the value of that input before creation you will get error because this field not exist in the form